# Java CouchDB Rest POST query response code 500

Tags: java, json, couchdb

I am trying to query a local CouchBD database with Java. I have only a small amount of experience of each. I can send the same post request to CouchDB via Postman and get the desired response. Can anyone suggest what might be wrong here?

Initially, I just need a working method which I can use to experiment and learn from.

I am happy to provide further information if required,

```
public static void Post_json() throws IOException {

        try {

            String query_url = "http://Admin:Admin@127.0.0.1:5984/job/_find";
            String json = "{\"selector\": {\"number\": 100100}}";

            URL url = new URL(query_url);
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setConnectTimeout(5000);
            conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=UFT-8");
            conn.setDoOutput(true);
            conn.setDoInput(true);
            conn.setRequestMethod("POST");

            OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();

            os.write(json.getBytes("UTF-8"));
            os.close();

            InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(conn.getInputStream());
            String result = IOUtils.toString(in, "UFT-8");

            System.out.println(result);

            in.close();
            conn.disconnect();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing more details about the error, I can only guess that it might be a `CORS` problem.

Try to configure `CORS` by changing `[http]` and `[cors]` entries within the configuration file `$COUCHDB_HOME/etc/local.ini` as follows:

```
[httpd]
enable_cors = true

[cors]
origins = *
methods = GET,POST,PUT,DELETE
credentials = true
```

Comment: I made the changes you suggest, but it still doesn't work. I am happy to provide more details about the error, what would be helpful?